# Flexbox centering not working with some height / width

Tags: html, css

I have a custom radio button, a `span` element is the border of the button and it has an `::after` that is the dot that fills the button. I want to center that dot inside the span, i am using flexbox for that but for some reason if i give the `::after` this values:

```
width: 1.5rem;
height: 1.5rem;
```

it does not work, it is a little bit to the right and bottom. However if I give both properties a value of `1.4rem` it's completely in the center.

Why is this happening?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  /* 1rem = 10px */
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

input[type='checkbox']+label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin: 30px;
}

input[type='checkbox']+label span {
  margin-right: 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50rem;
  border: 0.4rem solid #2b90d9;
}

input[type='checkbox']+label span::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 50rem;
  background-color: #2b90d9;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked+label span::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="radio" />
<label for="radio">test
  <span></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dealing with an uneven number of pixels on each side of the centered object.

*Consider this:* If you have a container that's 100 pixels wide, and inside you have a centered object that is 55 pixels wide, you're not going to have perfect centering (because 45 / 2 doesn't produce an equal number of whole pixels).

```
|   ----------------------------------------- 100px ------------------------------------ |
|               23px            |     centered 55px object     |             22px        |
```

In your code, 3rem and 1.5rem compute to 30px and 15px, respectively.

So here's the problem:

```
|   ------------------------------------------ 30px ------------------------------------ |
|                8px            |     centered 15px object     |            7px          |
```

This also explains why 1.4rem works:

```
|                8px            |     centered 14px object     |            8px          |
```

With an even length on the container and an odd length on the child (or vice versa), you can't have perfect centering. I would keep both elements either odd or even.

Comment: Perfect explanation my friend! So browsers does not use decimals? For example 45/2 would be 22.5, the browser just converts this to 23 or 22px?

Comment: @Michael_B Great explanation indeed. I guess that was it.

Comment: I'm not sure about fractional units. Also, I'm not sure if it's the browser or the screen. May be a good subject for a new question.